# marker icon isn't showing in Leaflet

Tags: reactjs, webpack, leaflet, webpack-4

I 've put together a very simple React / Leaflet demo but the marker icon is not showing at all.
Full running code is [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/modest-tree-7puvc?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark).

Here's what I have in my `componentDidMount` method:

```
componentDidMount() {
this.map = L.map("map-id", {
  center: [37.98, 23.72],
  zoom: 12,
  zoomControl: true
});

const mapboxAccessToken =
  "pk.eyJ1IjoibXBlcmRpa2VhcyIsImEiOiJjazZpMjZjMW4wOXJzM2ttc2hrcTJrNG9nIn0.naHhlYnc4czWUjX0-icY7Q";
L.tileLayer(
  "https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/{id}/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}?access_token={accessToken}",
  {
    attribution:
      'Map data &copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, <a href="https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, Imagery © <a href="https://www.mapbox.com/">Mapbox</a>',
    maxZoom: 25,
    id: "mapbox/streets-v11",
    accessToken: mapboxAccessToken
  }
).addTo(this.map);

L.marker([37.98, 23.72])
  .addTo(this.map)
  .bindPopup("a marker")
  .openPopup();
}
```

Basically, the popup is visible, but not the marker icon itself. I.e., here's what I see:

[image]

Comment: On my machine the icon is expressed as base64, but it apparently doesn't show up because it is malformed: `<img src='data:image/png;base64, ... GgIwYdwAAAAASUVORK5CYII=")marker-icon.png'`. Removing the suffix `")marker-icon.png` in the browser debugger makes the icon appear, but I don't know where it's coming from. In addition there is an empty square around the icon, which probably represents the missing drop shadow.

Comment: Related issue: https://github.com/PaulLeCam/react-leaflet/issues/453

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try to add an icon:

```
const myIcon = L.icon({
   iconUrl: 'myIcon.png',
   // ...
});

L.marker([37.98, 23.72], {icon: myIcon})
  .addTo(this.map)
```

Perhaps you have some problems with the default one: https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.6.0.html#icon-default

Comment: I'm accepting this answer since it led me to the correct solution in webpack (https://stackoverflow.com/a/60188233/274677)

Answer (score 29):

I'm using react-leaflet.  Here's how I did it.

```js
import markerIconPng from "leaflet/dist/images/marker-icon.png"
import {Icon} from 'leaflet'
```

then, later, inside the MapContainer:

```js
<Marker position={[lat, lng]} icon={new Icon({iconUrl: markerIconPng, iconSize: [25, 41], iconAnchor: [12, 41]})} />
```

Comment: Nice !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: I'm using nextjs and this almost worked for me. It wants a specific path instead of an imported image. Say your icon is ```marker-icon.png```. Place it under the static directory e.g. ```public``` and use ```new Icon({ iconUrl : '/marker-icon.png' ... })```

Comment: The best answer. And you can import any marker icon to use instead of the default one.

Answer (score 4):

Here's what worked for me in the end (I'm on webpack):

```
const defaultIcon = new L.icon({
  iconUrl: require('../node_modules/leaflet/dist/images/marker-icon.png'); // your path may vary ...
  iconSize: [8, 8],
  iconAnchor: [2, 2],
  popupAnchor: [0, -2]
});

generateMarkers().forEach( c=> {
   L.marker(c, {icon: defaultIcon}).addTo(this.map).bindPopup('a marker; yeah').openPopup();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

include this before in index.js file before calling render function.

```
import markerIcon from "../node_modules/leaflet/dist/images/marker-icon.png";
L.Marker.prototype.setIcon(L.icon({
  iconUrl:markerIcon
}))
```

Comment: This works like a charm in Vue 3, ES6.

Answer (score 2):

Just for reference, this is due to webpack trying to include the Marker Icon image file specified in Leaflet CSS as a static asset in  different folder and possibly file renaming (e.g. for finger printing); all this interferes with Leaflet algorithm which uses that image only as a pointer to its actual CSS images folder, which therefore can be completely missing after webpack build step.

See details in https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/issues/4968

I specifically made a Leaflet plugin to cover this issue: https://github.com/ghybs/leaflet-defaulticon-compatibility

> Retrieve all Leaflet Default Icon options from CSS, in particular all icon images URL's, to improve compatibility with bundlers and frameworks that modify URL's in CSS.

Unfortunately, it would still not work in CodeSandbox (or even in StackBlitz), because the latter does not handle these static assets. It is visible by just trying to use Leaflet Layers Control, which uses a very simple CSS background image, which is also missing in CodeSandbox.

But everything should be fine in your own environment.

demo in CodeSandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/elegant-swirles-yzsql

and in StackBlitz (same static assets issue): https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-vqgtxd?file=index.js

Answer (score 1):

I guess one simple way is just changes the image path:

```
L.Icon.Default.imagePath='images/'
```

I'm using react so I copied the folder `/node_modules/leaflet/dist/images` to `/public`.

Answer (score 0):

```
 L.Icon.Default.imagePath='/path_to_your_images';
    var icon = L.icon({
        iconUrl: 'marker-icon.png',
        shadowUrl: 'marker-shadow.png',

        iconSize:     [25, 41],
        shadowSize:   [30, 65],
        iconAnchor:   [12, 41],
        shadowAnchor: [7, 65]
    });
```

this solution works for me!